# localhost/joomla = Showing only Error not Work

Tags: joomla

I am facing the issue of `localhost/joomla` is not showing login page, just show word `Error`
I have attached permission details and other corresponding files. Please help me to solve this issue.

[image]

[image]

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: could you please share error logs from `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file

Comment: [Fri Jan 17 11:55:05.006982 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 8529] [client ::1:45144] PHP  12. JSessionHandlerJoomla->start() /var/www/html/joomla/libraries/joomla/session/handler/joomla.php:88
[Fri Jan 17 11:55:05.006990 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 8529] [client ::1:45144] PHP  13. JSessionHandlerJoomla->doSessionStart() /var/www/html/joomla/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php:50
[Fri Jan 17 11:55:05.006997 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 8529] [client ::1:45144] PHP  14. session_start() /var/www/html/joomla/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php:260

Comment: give me your mail id I will mail log file

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the database the site it's not connected.

Check your configuration.php (in the root of the site) for this parameters:

> public $dbtype = 'mysqli'; // Driver you are using to connect to the MySQL database.
>
> public $host = 'localhost'; // The host for the database. If it's in the same server, it's ok like this.
>
> public $user = 'root'; // Username for the database
>
> public $password = 'root'; // Password of the database
>
> public $db = 'NAME_OF_THE_DATABASE'; // Name of the database.